# How can I have my Windows Form application minimize to system taskbar?

Tags: windows, .net-3.5, taskbar

My dream is to make a very good, open source Help desk application for companies to use for free.

My client application will run on every client computer have minimize itself to the task bar. When the user click the icon, it'll open the actual Winform window.

I'm using .NET 3.5; is there a simple way to minimize/maximize from the taskbar?

Comment: Do you mean the system tray? (Next to the clock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- [C# Tip: Placing Your C# Application
  in the System Tray](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3336751)
- [How to Minimize an Application to
  the Taskbar Tray in C#](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/how-to-minimize-an-application-to-the-taskbar-tray-in-csharp)
- [Minimize window to system tray](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/Minimize_To_Tray.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you mean the system tray.  (The small icons next to the clock)

Set the form's `ShowInTaskbar` property to False, then make a `NotifyIcon` component and show the form in its Click event.

Comment: And what if you still want it displayed in the Task Bar, and only hidden on minimize?

Comment: Then set `ShowInTaskbar` to false when it's minimized by checking `FormWindowState` in the `Resize` event.